# how to construct Hypergraph

Tags: java, graph, jung

I'm developing an image retrieval approach using hypergraph

after a quick search on Google i found the jung Library which deal with hyper-graph but it focus most at visualization ,

so any one know jow to begin , any tutorial or algorithm for constructing hypergraph

thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Generally you construct a hypergraph just as you'd construct any other graph, via the API.  Have you looked at the API documentation?

Comment: i have tried un exmple of constructing hypergraph 
in graph visualisation they use Treebuilder but in case of hypergraph how to visualise it.
Moreover , my hypergraph may contain more than 3000 vertices so it well be hard to use GraphML

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to define/create/construct a hypergraph, or how to visualize it?

Comment: both 
but visualisation is not very important 
I have constructed an hypergraph with jung
there is a method for generating incidence matrix?

Comment: It would be trivial to generate an incidence matrix using the API.  What problem are you trying to solve that you think you need an incidence matrix for?

Comment: i have an optimization problem that i need to compute the incidence matrix to solve it

Comment: I don't know what form your optimization code expects the incidence matrix to be in.  If you don't actually have such code yet, however, it may be--depending on the nature of the optimization--that you don't need the data in the form of a matrix after all, and that simply passing in the Hypergraph and asking vertices for their incident edges and so forth will be sufficient.